# Why is it not possible to declare a constexpr non-static data member?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, constexpr, static-members

An attempt to create a member of a struct with constexpr attribute without being static result in a compiler error(see below). Why is that? for a single constant value will I have this value in memory until program is terminatted instead of just scope of struct? should I back to use a macro?

```
struct foo
{
  constexpr int n = 10;
  // ...
};

error: non-static data member cannot be constexpr; did you intend to make it static?
```

Comment: Well, copying it wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: Much better once in static memory than many times, one in each instance of the struct.

Comment: Why would you have a copy of `constexpr` for each object?

Comment: @NemanjaBoric `constexpr` is compile-time only, right? So if that's the case, why would you have one per instance? It wouldn't exist at runtime.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know the official rational. But surely it could lead to confusion. I, for one, can't see what it means for a non-static data member to be `constexpr`. Are you able to do the following?

```
struct foo {
  constexpr int n = 10;
  constexpr foo() { }
  constexpr foo(int n):n(n) { } // overwrite value of n
};
```

Or does it mean that the initializer must be constant always, i.e you are not allowed to write the above (because `n` is not constant/could potentially non-constant) but allowed to say

```
foo f = { 10 };
```

The rule that `constexpr int n` is simply ill-formed rather than being implicitly `static` seems good to me, as its semantics would not be clear IMO.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with `constexpr int n = 10` as it is an integral type every use of `n` during compilation should be substituted with its value just  like in case of `define`. The syntax is pretty clear, I don't understand why the standard doesn't allow it.