# Why constexpr should be static?

Tags: c++, static, constexpr

After reading [this](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/g/std-proposals/c/m6_ISkYUxD0) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046775/why-constexpr-must-be-static) I still feel confused about this kind of expressions:

```
static constexpr int = 0;
```

AFAIK, in C++:

- `static` ensures life-time memory address along whole execution and safe initialization with concurrent threads
- `constexpr` ensures time-compilation evaluation as rvalue, which means it shall have no memory address

They look contradictory to me. `static` ensures the variable will have a long-time memory address whereas `constexpr` ensures the opposite assumption. Surprisingly, the discussion in the first link mentions this:

```
constexpr int x = 3;
const int* p = &x;
```

How can we even obtain the memory address of `x` if it is an rvalue?

Could anyone explain it?

Comment: Could you be more explicit whether your are you asking about local scope static or namespace scope static? They have a different meaning and your stated understanding doesn't apply to both.

Comment: I don't believe `constexpr` and value category (evaluation as rvalue) has any connection.

Comment: My question comes from seeing many class members declared `static constexpr`, I am not sure which kind that should be. In any case, could you briefly explain both?

Comment: Your first link specifically contradicts a `constexpr` variable having no address.

Comment: @Victor Static class members are even more different form other static. You should specify your question.

Comment: just provide a complete example along the line of `struct foo { static constexpr int = 0; };` and different use of `static` if your question is about that. (see [mcve])

Comment: I saw that the `constexpr` variable has a memory address in the example of the first link (surprisingly to me), that is why I posted this question. We can use that snippet as a complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` has a number of meanings. In classes (per your comment), it means that the member is associated with the class, and not a specific instance (object) of that class.

For a `constexpr`, that makes a lot of sense. That's typically initialized by a value known to the compiler, and not from ctor arguments.

Comment: Have I understood you correctly? `static` ensures that there is only one variable for all objects whereas `constexpr` ensures that its initialization is done at compilation time. Thanks.

Comment: @Victor: Yes, exactly. (Also, there's one `static` variable even if there are **zero** objects).